# Google App Maker Relations

Tags: google-app-maker

App maker has relations to configure Primary and foreign key relation ship. I configure 1 to many relation, it creates parent column name in the child model.

I don't know how it works, it is taking the first column by default to save in the child model. I re ordered the fields but it is not changing the name and I have deleted the relation and re created but it is not reflecting.

Can any one explain how it works, Which field is configured as default primary key in the documentation also it is not mentioned any where.

Answer (score 0):

You can change relation names on both sides of the relation at any time without re-creating it:
[image: Relation insight]

**Drive Tables**

For drive tables App Maker internally maintains `_key`, that is primary/foreign key SQL analogue. How the relation is handled under the hood is not exposed.

**Cloud SQL**

For cloud SQL things are little bit more transparent. For new models App Maker will automatically add `id` field that is primary key for SQL table and when you create a relation App Maker will automatically add foreign key column to the Model from the 'many' side.

Comment: In the same projects, the first column from the parent model is referenced to second model. Whether the primary key is configured based on the parent column ?

Comment: If you are using CloudSQL, then you can connect to the database and see all PKs and FKs. If you are using Drive Tables, then only google developers know, how they organize the data.

Comment: So we don't know how it is organized in child model right

Comment: Yep, we don't know. Maybe it is part of child table, maybe it is stand alone table, maybe smth else. By you don't need this knowledge, since App Maker doesn't provide low-level API to manipulate such kind of things(at least for Drive Tables).